# Re-defne a Paragraph Range to Include a Subset of Words in the Paragraph

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, ms-office, office-interop

I'm using Microsoft.Interop.Word / C# to programmatically create a Word document. In a given paragraph, I need to change the color of words that occur between brackets "[" and "]"

The words are variable.

As I understand it, I need a Range object in order to set colors. I'm using the following code, which does not work:

```
// Add the paragraph.
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Paragraph pgf = document.Paragraphs.Add();

// Insert text into the paragraph.
pgf.Range.InsertBefore("JIRA Issue: " + jiraIssueId + " [" + statusName + "]");

//Get start and end locations of the brackets.
//These will define the location of the words to which I will apply colors.            
int startPos = pgf.Range.Text.IndexOf("[") + 1;
int endPos = pgf.Range.Text.IndexOf("]") - 1;

/* Attempt to change range start and end positions,
 so the range contains just the words between brackets.
 I've tried two methods.                  
*/
// The following line does not work.
pgf.Range.SetRange(startPos, endPos);

// And the following lines do not work either
pgf.Range.Start = startPos;
pgf.Range.End = endPos;

// Attempt to Change color. The following line changes the color of entire paragraph:
pgf.Range.Font.Color = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdColor.wdColorRed;

/* The following always prints the entire contents of the paragraph, 
  and not just the words between the brackets. So my attempts at narrowing
  the range were not successful.
*/
Console.WriteLine(pgf.Range.Text);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SetRange doesn't work because you can't change beginning or ending of a paragraph. It just begins where it begins. You need an "own" range that you can modify. What a luck there exists the property Duplicate of a Range. As MSDN says: `By duplicating a Range object, you can change the starting or ending character position of the duplicate range without changing the original range.`

First I assume that the MS Word namspace is included:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
```

So after calculating startPos and endPos you should change your code to (**UPDATED**):

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range rng = pgf.Range.Duplicate;
rng.MoveEnd(WdUnits.wdCharacter, endPos - rng.Characters.Count);
rng.MoveStart(WdUnits.wdCharacter, startPos);
rng.Font.Color = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdColor.wdColorRed;
```

and it should work. (Just don't decrement the endPos some lines above; but you will realize it)

Comment: Thanks, Fratyx. I tried your suggestion. After I call Duplicate, the new range object points to the same as the original. But when I call SetRange as you indicated, the startPos and endPos are interpreted as relative to the **start of the document** This is very strange.

Comment: Yes, Steve, you're right. Seems to be a little bit more complicated. SetRange seems to be relative to the whole text. I updated my code by moving the start and end of the range.

Comment: Fratyx, absolutely brilliant, thanks! I had devised a workaround of looping through the words in the paragraph, but it is not elegant like your solution.

Comment: Thank you but to be honest there surely are more elegant solution. (E.g. the Find object?) Unfortunately until now I couldn't find a really good explanation of the philosophy of the MS Word framework.

Comment: Fratyx, yes I was thinking about that too. I've worked in other document APIs and they seem to make it easier to isolate words to which that one needs to apply styling. Microsoft's MSDN documentation on the Word framework is good in terms of simply describing various properties and methods, but I've noticed it's very lacking in explaining **why** one might use methods, and usually does not have good code samples. Thanks again.