# C# How can i get part of the word line's color in a word paragraph range

Tags: c#, ms-word

am read WORD document with Word.ApplicationClass()

and the document style is kind this(**doc**)

> AAAAA
>
> BBBB
>
> ①AAA  ②BBB  ③CCC(third part is red)  ④DDD

and i get every line by using

> String docLine= doc.paragraphs[i].range.text.Trim();

and run [doc.paragraphs[3].range.text.Trim();] you get(**line 3**)

> ①AAA  ②BBB  ③CCC(third part is red)  ④DDD

![enter image description here][2]  a line with 4 parts words of different color.

here is my problem, when i want to get the **Red third part** of the line
i dont know how to get it.

cause i dont know **how to set a sub-Range in paragraphs[3].range** which contains what i want.

i'v checked MSDN and only find u can set a Range's start and end when it's document.Range.

so what im asking is can someone tell me **how to set a sub-range in a paragraphy[i].range. so that i can use range.font.colorindex**

**or**

if there is no way to do that then **how can i get the color information when i read every prat of the line so that when i read the red part i can know.**

Thanks

Comment: May you precise 1) Once identified the "③CCC" text part as range, what is the objective (replacement, reformating, ...) 2) Is the document read a "static" one used as a model or is it produced by another application ?

Comment: thank you for comment. ive found the way to locate the part i want. By using  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range rng = doc.paragraphs[3].Range.Duplicate; i can get an manipulable range( u cant change paragraphs.range)

Answer (score 0):

thank you for all that help. ive found the way to locate the part i want.
From this que:[Re-defne a Paragraph Range to Include a Subset of Words in the Paragraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26309013/re-defne-a-paragraph-range-to-include-a-subset-of-words-in-the-paragraph)
seems i didnt search right hum~

By using

> Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range rng =
>   doc.paragraphs[3].Range.Duplicate;

i can get an manipulable range( u cant change paragraphs.range),

and by using

> rng.MoveEnd(WdUnits.wdCharacter, endPos - rng.Characters.Count);
>   rng.MoveStart(WdUnits.wdCharacter, startPos);

i can locate what i want

tips: range.setRange(int start, int end) will always(i think) relative the start and end of the document. it's helpless when u try to work on a sentence or a line.